# debezium how to commit offset manually

Tags: debezium

I use debezium to sync data from Postgres to flink, and create engine use this code

```java
this.engine = DebeziumEngine.create(Connect.class)
            .using(properties)
            .notifying(debeziumConsumer)
            .using((success, message, error) -> {
                if (!success && error != null) {
                    this.reportError(error);
                }
            })
            .build();
```

I want to call `ChangeEventSourceCoordinator#commitOffset` when flink doing checkpoint, but `coordinator` is private in `BaseSourceTask` and `task` is private in `EmbeddedEngine`, so I can't call `commitOffset` in my code, Is there any other way to achieve manual commit?

```java
public final class EmbeddedEngine implements DebeziumEngine<SourceRecord>{
       private SourceTask task;
}
```

```java
public abstract class BaseSourceTask extends SourceTask {
       private ChangeEventSourceCoordinator coordinator;
}
```